# Android - app has been rejected because it is primarily child-directed and uses the Google API to access Google Account data

Tags: android

After I uploaded my app to the google play console I recieved this message :

App status: Your app has been rejected because it is primarily child-directed and uses the Google API to access Google Account data. Apps that target both children and older audiences (mixed audience) may use Google sign-in or Google Play Game Services as an optional feature, but login cannot be automatic or required.

Eligibility issues:

Google Play developer policies do not allow the use of any Google API that accesses Google Account data (including Google Sign-in and Google Play Games Services) in apps directed primarily to children.

what should I do ?

Comment: Not sure if changing the app rating would help.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: @fullMoon that's not the problem :/

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

if you Opt in to Designed for Families
[Primarily Child-Directed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhF7F.png) to YES then not use any Google Sign-in and Google Play Games Services. Because its violating Google Policy. Opt out 
to Designed for Families and send update. Hopefully your app will be live.